# Action Script 2 - using if-statement alongside random?

Tags: flash, random, if-statement, actionscript-2

I've made an animation in Flash (CS 5.5 if that matters) of a coin, a die and an 8 ball, which once clicked you can toss/roll/shake the respective object on clicking the object (which are all buttons already), and for a random result to be computed, determining what frame to gotoAndPlay.

I assume the process behind a coin toss/die roll is similar so I'll base the die roll and the 8 ball off of the coin toss… I've tried to find tutorials on how to do something like I'm doing it but the method's off.

I've had no problems in generating a number randomly but I don't have any idea on where to go to from that.

EDIT: I didn't have any code to paste when I originally wrote this someone suggested I try

```
(int)(Math.random()*2) 
if((int)(Math.random()*2) == 0)
  {gotoAndPlay("label a");} 
else if((int)(Math.random()*2) == 1)
  {gotoAndPlay("label b");
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: What do you want exactly to do ? Paste some code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand your question correctly, there is the random number you need to generate and then go to the respective frame.
Assuming you have already created your animations, you will need to paste a code something like this on your movieclip button

on(release){

```
var xy=Math.round(Math.random() * 2)+1 //"2" is the number of frames you have
gotoAndStop(xy);
```

}

you might need to replace gotoAndStop with mc_name.gotoAndStop if the button and animation mc are not the same.

Tell me how it goes!

Editted: 
Math.random()*2 will very rarely generate a whole number. Hence you should use the round option to round the number. But if you are expecting a number either 1 or 0, you should just use Math.round(Math.random())
Also the issue you have is that you are using the Math.random at your if statements
What your code should look like is :

```
var num:Number=Math.round(Math.random());
if(num==0){
//Do something
}else{
//Do Something
}
```

If you are expecting more than 2 cases, then

```
var num:Number=Math.round(Math.random()*numberofcases);
switch(num){
case 0:
//do something
break;
case 1:
//do something
break;
case 2:
//do something 
break;
...
default:
//do something as default
break
}
```

This should work for you.

Do tell me how it goes and accept the answer if it works!
Thanks.

Comment: That didn't work for me unfortunately.
Am I supposed to put in values for x and y or something?
I've edited the main question with a code that a friend gave me but also didn't work.